# Failed to craeate Dockerfile Openjdk image /bin/sh: apt-get: not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

im getting the following error `/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found`
and this is my dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:17

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

COPY target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: So apparently the OpenJDK image isn't based on Ubuntu/Debian

Comment: that's clear, so do you have any idea which linux dist is based on else which command should i run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenJDK:17 image is based on Oracle Linux 7 which use microdnf as package manager.